# How to join two tables and return one row in PL/SQL?

Tags: join, plsql

I have 2 tables which names are FIRST and USERS. In FIRST table i have USERID1,USERID2 and USERID3 columns. And USERS table i save USERID's names and surnames values. If i join tables;

```
SELECT f.userid1, f.userid2, f.userid3, u.name, u.surname
FROM users u, first f
WHERE f.userid1=u.userid AND f.userid2=u.userid AND f.userid3=u.userid
```

i want to return this result in 1 row like;

```
121314 name surname 131415 name surname 141516 name surname
```

FIRST table result example;

```
no   no2             userid1  userid2  userid3  ...
7    100000545       121314   131415  141516   ....
```

USER TABLE

```
id        name      surname
121314    black      smoke
131415    jack       shephard
141516    john       locke
```

i want to result like user table but i have to join because coming result must according to records from FIRST table

Comment: May we ask why you want this unusual formatting in your output?

Comment: what is unusual? FIRST and USER table results are line by line. in question not like a table.

Comment: I've edited my answer, you might want to check.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, to retrieve the result in one row, you will need to use aggregate function. You might try adapting the following query to your requirements:

```
WITH first AS
(
  SELECT
    7 AS no
    ,100000545 AS no2
    ,121314 AS userid1
    ,131415 AS userid2
    ,141516 AS userid3
  FROM
    dual
)
, users AS
(
  SELECT
    DECODE(LEVEL
      ,1,121314
      ,2,131415
      ,3,141516
    ) AS id
    ,DECODE(LEVEL
      ,1,'black'
      ,2,'jack'
      ,3,'john'
    ) AS name
    ,DECODE(LEVEL
      ,1,'smoke'
      ,2,'shephard'
      ,3,'locke'
    ) AS surname
  FROM
    dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 4
)
SELECT
  TRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, s.id||' '||s.name||' '||s.surname||' ')).EXTRACT('//text()').getClobVal()) AS one_row_result
FROM
  first f
  ,users s
WHERE
  s.id IN (f.userid1, f.userid2, f.userid3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily about plsql, but sql in general

In your query "u.userid" will always be a field in the same row.
 So, you won't get any result as long as f.userid1, f.userid2, f.userid3 don't hold the same value. What i think you want to achieve is to get 3 users, whose ids are stored in first table, so you have to reference "user"table three times.
To get a row as in your example, a query would look like:

```
SELECT f.userid1, u_first.name , u_first.surname, 
       f.userid2, u_second.name, u_second.surname,
       f.userid3, u_third.name, u_third.surname
FROM users u_first, users u_second, users u_third, first f 
WHERE f.userid1=u_first.userid 
  AND f.userid2=u_second.userid 
  AND f.userid3=u_third.userid
```

Someone will surely provide a correct join here.

**Edit**

For your example data this select **will** result in

```
121314 black smoke 131415 jack shepard 141516 john locke
```

Note however, that you don't specify for which row in First table you want to get this join, so you will get a result row for each row in First table, if rows from User table can satisfy those conditions (I hope you have constraints set properly)

If you want to fetch only one row for one specific Field row, add

```
AND f.no=7
```

at the end of the query

If the output you wish to receive is:

```
121314    black      smoke
131415    jack       shephard
141516    john       locke
```

try:

```
SELECT f.userid1, u.name ,u.surname, 
FROM users u, first f 
WHERE f.userid1=u.userid 
  OR f.userid2=u.userid 
  OR f.userid3=u.userid
  AND f.no=7
```

This is a good way to actually test, whether all users with those IDs exist in the database.
But remember, that the order in result will be the same as order of items in User table, so it won't neccessarly be the same as f.first and then f.second and then f.third

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the author wants either.  Actually, I proceeded assuming the query in the OP were sound, which it is not.  This is a bad question in my opinion.

Comment: I agree, but if you just started learning sql you might not accurately understand what happens when you select rows from table, so author might not know that u.userid would have the same value for each row processed.

Comment: I will only say that you should use an explicit `JOIN` as this is the preferred method (AFAIK), and it makes the query easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, i pointed that out at the end of my answer, but i would never write a correct join the first time

Comment: Nothing happen. no result is coming. And all userids are different. This is not my database, many years ago they did like tihis

Comment: @ROOT give us example data from your database (both tables) and exact output you want to achieve.